# Segmentation fault starting Chromium in Antegros

Tags: antergos, chrome

I have Antergos/Arch. Some months ago I upgraded chromium using Pacman in a routine system upgrade. After the upgrade chromium wouldn't start and it'd throw me a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

I assumed it was just a bug that would eventually get fixed, so I downgraded to my previous version (`65.0.3325.181-5`) and forgot about it until today. Today I tried upgrading Chromium again to the most recent version (`67.0.3396.87-2`) only to find out that I still get the some error. So I think it's unlikely that this is a bug from chromium.

For the time being I have no idea what's causing this and I have no idea how to investigate this problem. I'm using a Samsung np900 and, besides this issue, I've had never any problems with my installation. (Chrome, by the way, works just fine.)

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you deleted/moved your profile and restarted? If that doesn't work, you'll need [more intensive debugging](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Step-by-step_debugging_guide#Segmentation_faults).

Comment: @jasonwryan I have removed my `~/.config/chromium` and upgraded, with the same result. I'm not sure where exactly my profile is stored, but afaik it should be all contained in that directory, right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to move to gdb.

Comment: On Mint/Ubuntu I noticed that the code requires a more recent version of `libnss3` but the deb file wasn't set up to include that as a dependency, so it wasn't auto installed by `apt`.  Possibly similar situation?  Check `ldd /path/to/chromium-binary` to make sure all libraries are being found, etc.

Comment: @jasonwryan thanks for the tip. Based on that I actually found I just had to delete `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf`. It was pointing to a directory in `/home/antergos` that was remnant from the liveUSB installation for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer for completeness. The issue was that `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf` was pointing to a directory in `/home/antergos/` instead of my user's home directory. This was apparently a bug reported by more people but that is now fixed. I just had to delete this file since it is not used anymore.

Comment: I've been facing the same problem for about the same time. This worked for me. Thanks for posting the solution. :)

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta glad to help, my man